# Cannot install DualBand Wireless-AC 7260 (intel wireless driver) on dell laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

This might be simple but I am new to linux. I am running ubuntu 19.10.

I have problems with wifi. The additional drivers show that I need to install drivers for intel's DualBand Wireless-AC 7260.

I downloaded [the iwlwifi-7260-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz) from intel and extracted it.

Using instructions from "README.iwlwifi-7260-ucode" I copied the file `iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode` to `/lib/firmware`. 
Now I am stuck.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

[image: Driver window gui picture]

Comment: The driver and firmware for your 7260 are already present in Ubuntu 19.10; I am using mine right now! If your wireless isn't working as expected, something else is wrong. "I have problems with wifi." Please tell us in detail what the problem is. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The wifi connection drops at times. very often, as many as three times in 30min. The reconnection takes place automatically. some times it returns back with an authentication error, although I gave in the right password. Let me know if you need more details. My final goal is to install the wifi driver and check. Can you please help me installing this driver. Danke

Comment: In terminal do `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service`  That should fix it, you don't need backport-iwlwifi-dkms but kernel 5.3.0-40 might still have issues